# split a string by the last patterns

Tags: r, string, design-patterns

I have some data like this:

```
vtab = read.table(textConnection("uid=123455,ou=usuarios,ou=gm,dc=intra,dc=planej,dc=gov,dc=de  
                                 uid=123456,ou=bsa,dc=plant,dc=gov,dc=de  
                                 uid=123457,ou=reg,ou=regfns,dc=sero,dc=gov,dc=de  
                                 uid=123458,ou=reg,ou=regbhe,dc=sero,dc=gov,dc=de    
                                 uid=123459,ou=sede,ou=regbsa,dc=sero,dc=gov,dc=de    
                                 uid=123450,ou=reg,ou=regbhe,dc=sero,dc=gov,dc=de"))
```

I would like split this data. Firstly split the data in two groups including just the **uid=** number and the third last description in **dc=**. Like thus:

```
     [,1]         [,2]      
[1,] "123455"   "plant" 
[2,] "123456"   "planej" 
[3,] "123457"   "sero" 
[4,] "123458"   "sero" 
[5,] "123459"   "sero"
```

Any helps are enjoyed :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
Col1 <- gsub('uid=(\\d+).*', '\\1', vtab$V1)
Col2 <- gsub('.*dc=(.*)(,dc=.*){2}', '\\1', vtab$V1)
data.frame(Col1, Col2)
#     Col1   Col2
#1 123455 planej
#2 123456  plant
#3 123457   sero
#4 123458   sero
#5 123459   sero
#6 123450   sero
```

Answer (score 1):

Without regex:

```
dat <- strsplit(as.character(vtab[,1]), ",", fixed = TRUE)
vapply(dat, function(x) {
  uid <- gsub("uid=", "", x[[1]], fixed = TRUE)
  dc <- grep("dc", x, value = TRUE)
  dc <- dc[length(dc) - 2]
  dc <- gsub("dc=", "", dc, fixed = TRUE)
  c(uid, dc)
}, c("a", "a"))

#     [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5]     [,6]    
#[1,] "123455" "123456" "123457" "123458" "123459" "123450"
#[2,] "planej" "plant"  "sero"   "sero"   "sero"   "sero"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use gsub.  Something like below. Use readLines to read data. Hope it helps!

```
    x =   readLines(textConnection("uid=123455,ou=usuarios,ou=gm,dc=intra,dc=planej,
    ... ,dc=de" ))

    ## Create a dataframe XX
    ##1. UID
    XX <- as.data.frame (gsub("\\D","",x) )
    colnames(XX) <- c('uid')
    XX
    uid
    1 123455
    2 123456
    3 123457
    4 123458
    5 123459
```